# UWP Image not updating/reloading

Tags: c#, image, uwp, uwp-xaml, viewbox

I know there are numerous questions similar to this on SO, but none so far have fixed the issue or shown a solution that works.

In a UWP app, I have an `Image` (inside a `ViewBox`) whose Source gets changed by the user selecting a new image.  I've confirmed that there are no Exceptions thrown anywhere in the code, and everything in the below switch-case works perfectly.  I've tried using `InvalidateArrange()`, `InvalidateMeasure()`, and `UpdateLayout()` on the Image, and `UpdateLayout()` on the `ViewBox`, but nothing seems to work.  The initial image is removed as the code runs, but the new image isn't displayed, it just shows a blank space.

Can somebody please look over the code below and see if you can find the problem?  I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking, I just can't seem to find what it is.

**C# Code**

```
private async void ChangeIcon(int selection)
{
    try
    {
        switch (selection)
        {
            case 0:
                imageEntry.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///FtpSharp/Assets/ftpRed.png"));
                break;
            case 1:
                imageEntry.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///FtpSharp/Assets/ftpOrange.png"));
                break;
            case 2:
                imageEntry.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///FtpSharp/Assets/ftpYellow.png"));
                break;
            case 3:
                imageEntry.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///FtpSharp/Assets/ftpGreen.png"));
                break;
            case 4:
                imageEntry.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///FtpSharp/Assets/ftpBlue.png"));
                break;
            case 5:
                imageEntry.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///FtpSharp/Assets/ftpPurple.png"));
                break;
            case 6:
                imageEntry.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///FtpSharp/Assets/tpPink.png"));
                break;
            case 7:
                imageEntry.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///FtpSharp/Assets/ftpTeal.png"));
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog
        {
            Title = "Exception found!",
            Content = ex.ToString(),
            CloseButtonText = "Understood"
        };
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }           
}
```

**ViewBox/Image XAML**

```
<Viewbox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="5,15,5,0">
    <Image x:Name="imageEntry" Source="Assets/SquircleX.png" Tapped="ImageEntry_TappedAsync" />
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Select one of the images in the Solution Explorer and check the Build Action in Properties window. Is it set to Content and is it Copy Always?

Comment: They we're set to Content, but not to Copy Always.  This didn't correct it though, but your actual answer did.

Comment: When modify the mage source. the old source removed, but new one does not display, right?

Comment: Correct.  It's working now, Martin's answer fixed it.

Comment: I meant his answer that is posted, about removing the project name from the ms-appx path.

Comment: Like this `ms-appx:///Assets/test.jpg`, right?

Comment: Correct, precisely like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the URI you are using - remove the `FtpSharp` part, for example:

```
ms-appx:///Assets/ftpRed.png
```

The reason is that `ms-apps:///` already points to the root of the installation folder of your app, so the `Assets` folder will be deployed directly there.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you immensely!  I was actually including the FTPSharp portion as I found another SO answer that said to include "[Project Name]"... apparently they were mistaken. :)

Comment: Great, glad it helped :-) . Happy coding!